# Azure search exception when publishing

Tags: publishing, azure-search

I have an issue where I see the following exception when trying to publish an item for a particular template:

```
Exception: Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure.Schema.SchemaMergeException
Message: Conflict between local and remote schemas in field 'frequency': 'Edm.String' and 'Collection(Edm.String)' are incompatible
Source: Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure
 at Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure.Schema.SearchServiceSchemaSynchronizer.MergeSchemas(IEnumerable`1 localSchema, IEnumerable`1 incomingSchema)
 at Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure.Schema.SearchServiceSchemaSynchronizer.SyncRemoteService(IEnumerable`1 sourceSchema, IEnumerable`1 incomingSchema)
 at Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure.Schema.SearchServiceSchemaSynchronizer.<>c__DisplayClass11_0.<EnsureIsInSync>b__0()
 at Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure.Utils.Retryer.RetryPolicy.Execute(Action action)
 at Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure.Http.SearchService.PostDocumentsImpl(ICloudBatch batch)
 at Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure.Http.SearchService.PostDocuments(ICloudBatch batch)
 at Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure.Http.CompositeSearchService.<>c__DisplayClass11_0.<PostDocuments>b__0(ISearchService searchService)
 at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.<>c__DisplayClass17_0`1.<ForWorker>b__1()
 at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvokeWithArg(Task childTask)
 at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c__DisplayClass176_0.<ExecuteSelfReplicating>b__0(Object )"}
```

The frequency field is a Multilist. We haven't added any specific index configuration for this field, but we have configured the index to index all fields.

This prevents the item being indexed correctly in the web database. It doesn't appear to be a problem for the master, which seems strange because the index has the same configuration.

What exactly does this exception mean and how can I resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This occurred because of items inheriting multiple templates with the field 'frequency' defined more than once with different types.

The issue is described in this article: https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/137856

Renaming one fixes the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same exception while rebuilding the index.
In my case there was only one field(no any other field with same name).
When I saw this field in index,the field type was Edm.String.
But in sitecore the field type was Number which equates to Edm.Double in azure.
So there was a mismatch with local schema and remote schema.
I did below steps to resolve the issue:

1. Stop Sitecore instance.
2. Remove Affected indexes.
3. Start sitecore instance.
4. Rebuild the affected indexes.